# DataGridView not updating when additional rows are added to the bound DataSource unless I null it out first

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winForms `DataGridView` bound to a `List<MyObjectType>`.  My problem is that once I do the initial `myDataGridView.DataSource = myObjectList;` that adding/removing elements from the list is not reflected in the displayed DataGridView even though in the debugger the row count on `myDataGridView.DataSource` does update.

I'm able to force the DGV to update the displayed rows if I null the datasource before reassigning the list to it.  This looks ugly though and I'm wondering if I didn't miss an easier way to do this.

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = null;
myDataGridView.DataSource = myObjectList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List<T>` collection does not support change notifications, so the `DataGridView` will never be able to detect when you add/remove elements. Consider using `ObservableCollection<T>`, which *does* support change notifications.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` will not work for `DataGridView`. `BindingList<T>` is a collection type for binding in `DataGridView` or `DataTable`